# Getting a number from a subset

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this in an interview:
You have a subset `D` of decimal digits `[0-9]`  and a calculator with a subset `O` of allowed mathematical operations `O c {+,-,*,/}`.
Given a number from 0 to 999, would it be possible to generate this number using the subset numbers and the calculator.
For example, given `D = {1,3,4,5}` and `O = {*,-}`, to get `129` you can do this: `35*4-11`
It is required that the last possible digit and operation combination should be used

## EDIT:

### I'm rewriting the specs in case my original post wasn't cealr

Based on the description above, the question can be broken down into this:

#### Inputs:

A set of Nonempty digits `D ⊆ {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`
A set of mathematical operators `C ⊆ {+,-,*,/}`
A number **Target** between 0 and 999

#### specs

You have a calculator to which you can pass any digit from D and perform any operator of C
You need to use the calculator in a way that finally gets the number **Target**

#### restrictions

- The calculator ACCEPTS NO PARENTHESIS, all the operations are
  performed in the sequence of appearance, i.e `1+2+3*4 = 3+3*4= 9*4 =
  36`
- The calculator can be return results in the range 0-999
- **Target** must be generated using the fewest "keyboard clicks" possible, this includes both the length of the digits of the numbers used as well (999 = 3 clicks) as the operations (each operation is 1 click)

Thus, 129 from the example above can be also generated using (for instance) `1111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-...` but that would use more keyboard click than 35*4-11

There were other trivial restrictions in the full question but I tried to summarize the algorithmic part in here

Comment: You related an interesting anecdote but didn't ask any question.

Comment: Are brackets allowed?

Comment: Presumably the subsets must be non-empty...

Comment: @twalberg if at least one of them is empty, we cannot generate any number, obviously

Comment: Even if O is empty, we can still generate a number consisting of any combination of digits ...dd... in D. If we are going to be formal, might as well be thorough :)

Comment: "It is required that the last possible digit and operation combination should be used" - what does it mean?  Unclear.  What is "last possible digit", and what is "last operation combination"?

Comment: Perhaps is a typo? Maybe should be "least possible". That throws a wrench into your solution @user31264

Comment: @RayfenWindspear if he means that we need the shortest possible expression in terms of the total number of digits and operations, then imho it would be virtually impossible to solve in sub-exponentional time, as long as we have subtraction and/or division.

Comment: @user31264 Indeed. None of the problems/solutions in my Computational Theory course were ever concerned with length limits. They were deemed a complexity not worth pursuing as well as an impossibility in the general case.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear if we don't care about time, then it is trivial to find the shortest possible expression, as long as we know one exists.

Comment: Can intermediate results be arbitrarily long?

Comment: No, the calculator works sequentially and any result outside the range would cause an error!

Comment: You can use Dijkstra's algorithm for this.  The vertexes of the graph are all the numbers you can make, the start vertex is 0, the edges are all the (operator,number) you can type, and the cost of each edge is the number of keystrokes it takes.  The shortest path to the target is the answer.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I think you're onto something here, I'll try to code it and see how it goes! Good thinking !

Comment: @MattTimmermans how would you construct the graph though?

Comment: No need to actually construct the graph.  I would just make a node for each vertex (number), and they all have the same edges, which I can enumerate easily.

Comment: Ok let's say there is a graph with nodes from 0 to 999, and 129 is the target number, how would you traverse the graph considering the allowed operations to reach this number?